# How to make dropdown in Yii2 from one record

Tags: yii2

Is it possible to make dropdown in Yii2 from two column in one row  table like this:

[image: table content]

I want `dropdown` list like this:

[image: dropdown form]

Comment: Can you show source data for this dropdown?

Comment: are you selecting  a single row from the database table to create a dropdown ?

Comment: @rob006, i just make the dropdown in my image  to simplify my question, `<select >
<option>  </option>
<option> Value_column_1 </option>
<option> Value_column_2 </option>

</select>`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, yes

Comment: see the answer below i posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided any details of the model you are using for the dropdown so I will demonstrate the example with `Phone` model and the fields are `id`, `phone`, `area_code`, just for the sake of understanding.

This is the data for `phone` table:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | phone       | area_code |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | 03214442021 | 021       |
|  2 | 03214452520 | 051       |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

Now, if you are selecting a single row from the database and trying to list all the `columns` from the single row inside the `drop-down` you can use the `array_filter` to filter out all the `attributes` into an array and then assign that array to the `drop-down` options.

Although you can use the same approach and use `array_filter` inside the `foreach` if you are selecting all the rows from the table, the difference would be the layout of the drop down.

When selecting a single row you will get the drop-down as follows:

[image]

And if you are selecting all the rows from the table the dropdown will look like below:

[image]

In your controller, you can do the following:

## For Single Row

```
public function actionPhone($id){
    $model = Phone::findOne($id);
    $rows = array_filter($model->attributes);
    return $this->render('drop-down', ['rows' => $rows]);
}
```

## For Multiple Rows

```
public function actionPhone(){
    $phone = Phone::find()->all();
    foreach ($phone as $model) {
        $rows[] = array_filter($model->attributes);
    }
    return $this->render('drop-down', ['rows' => $rows]);
}
```

The view part remains the same for both of the cases above, inside your view where you are creating the drop-down assign the rows to the options.

You can build the dropdown using `yii\helpers\Html` or `ActiveForm`.

```
<?= yii\helpers\Html::dropDownList('my-options',null,$rows) ?>
```

**Note: The dropdown option `text` is the value of the `column` and the dropdown option `value` is the column `name`. Means the first option in drop-down `['id'=>1]` the `id` will be the value and `1` will be the text displayed for the option.**

---

## EDIT

If you need to use the value for both the option and text you might need to use [`\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#map()-detail) where you can pass closure to the `$from` and `$to` means an anonymous function that way you can have the column value as `key` and `value` both like below:

```
Array(
    [1]=>1,
    [03214442021]=>03214442021 ,
    [021]=>021
)
```

So change your action to the following:

```
public function actionPhone($id){
        $model = Phone::findOne($id);
        $rows=\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(array_filter($model->attributes),function($item){
            return $item;
        },function($item){
            return $item;
        });
        return $this->render('drop-down', ['rows' => $rows]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your respons but how if i want the dropdown option value is also the value of the column?

Comment: See the **`Edit`** part @eniac05