# How to make dropdown list in Yii2 with ArrayHelper

Tags: yii2

I want to make dropdownlist **from single record**, I have two table like this:

[image: the tables]

Column `prodi_pilihan_1_id` and `prodi_pilihan_2_id` **referenced** from `prodi_penerima` table.

I want make dropdown for column `prodi_pilihan_1_id` and `prodi_pilihan_2_id` but the option text is from `prodi_penerima` that is `nama_prodi_penerima` so the dropdown be like this:

```
<select>
    <option value= '2'> BBB  </option>
    <option value= '4'> DDD  </option>
</select>
```

So suggest from [How to make dropdown in Yii2 from one record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764216/how-to-make-dropdown-in-yii2-from-one-record), I created controller like this:

```
 $model4 = Pendaftar::find()
  ->select(['pro1.id_prodi_penerima as id_prodi_pilihan_1','pro1.nama_prodi_penerima as prodi_pilihan_1','pro2.id_prodi_penerima as id_prodi_pilihan_2','pro2.nama_prodi_penerima as prodi_pilihan_2'])
  ->from('pendaftar') 
  ->leftJoin('prodi_penerima as pro1', 'pro1.id_prodi_penerima=pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_1')
  ->leftJoin('prodi_penerima as pro2', 'pro2.id_prodi_penerima=pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_2')
  ->andWhere(['=','id_user_pendaftar',$id])
  ->asArray()
  ->One();
   $rows=\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(array_filter([$model4['prodi_pilihan_1'],$model4['prodi_pilihan_2']]),function($item){
        return $item;
    },function($item){
        return $item;
    });
 //return $this->render('lulus_ujian', ['rows' => $rows]);
    return $this->renderAjax('lulus_ujian', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'rows' => $rows,
    ]);
```

I render that into the view and then into the form, the form is like this:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'status_lulus_tes_pendaftar')->dropDownList([ 'yes' => 'Yes', 'no' => 'No', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'prodi_lulus')->dropDownList($rows, ['prompt' => '']) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'ket_lulus_ujian')->textarea(['rows' => '6']) ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The dropdown is working, **but the value and the option is having the same value**:

```
<select>
    <option value= 'BBB'> BBB  </option>
    <option value= 'DDD'> DDD  </option>
</select>
```

I want save the model where the option value is `id_prodi_penerima`.
What I must do so the option value is 2 and 4 like this:

```
<select>
    <option value= '2'> BBB  </option>
    <option value= '4'> DDD  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you add the `print_r($model4)` , what does it show, and the question you are referring to previously it was for one row, do you still want to draw the menu the same way , means you want to show all the columns in the dropdown, for a single row, and use the option value as another column rather than keeping the same columns for the options value and text.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, the result from print_r($model4), `Array ( [id_prodi_pilihan_1] => 2 [prodi_pilihan_1] => BBB [id_prodi_pilihan_2] => 4 [prodi_pilihan_2] => DDD )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case using `ArrayHelper` does not make any sense, since you need to process only one record and you know exact structure of required array. So just build it directly from query results:

```
$model4 = Pendaftar::find()
    ->select([
        'pro1.id_prodi_penerima as id_prodi_pilihan_1', 
        'pro1.nama_prodi_penerima as prodi_pilihan_1', 
        'pro2.id_prodi_penerima as id_prodi_pilihan_2', 
        'pro2.nama_prodi_penerima as prodi_pilihan_2'
    ])
    ->from('pendaftar')
    ->leftJoin('prodi_penerima as pro1', 'pro1.id_prodi_penerima=pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_1')
    ->leftJoin('prodi_penerima as pro2', 'pro2.id_prodi_penerima=pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_2')
    ->andWhere(['=', 'id_user_pendaftar', $id])
    ->asArray()
    ->one();
$rows = [
    $model4['id_prodi_pilihan_1'] => $model4['prodi_pilihan_1'], 
    $model4['id_prodi_pilihan_2'] => $model4['prodi_pilihan_2'],
];
return $this->renderAjax('lulus_ujian', [
    'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    'rows' => $rows,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think first you have to check what you receive with the `$rows` variable. Do a variable dump and check whether your `$rows` variable contains data as follows (Assuming that you expect only 2 pairs).

`array(2) { ["2"]=> string(3) "BBB" ["4"]=> string(3) "DDD" }`

Else, you have to pass a new array with the above format to render expected results in your dropdown list.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the var_dump($rows) give result like this `array(2) { ["BBB"]=> string(3) "BBB" ["DDD"]=> string(3) "DDD" }`

Comment: It means your query is not returning what you expect @eniac05. Please double check your query especially the joins and where condition. It seems like you have over complicated your query.